# How to use _spawn or _exec for bootstrapping?

Tags: c, exec, command-line-arguments, dynamic-arrays, spawn

After writing the following program, it does not appear to pass arguments to the called application. While researching [_spawnv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zt1y878%28VS.80%29.aspx) and what it can do, [_execvp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/431x4c1w(VS.80).aspx) was found as what appeared to be a suitable alternative. Does anyone see the problem in the source code and know what needs to be done to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <process.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int index;
    char** args;
    args = (char**) malloc((argc + 1) * sizeof(char*));
    args[0] = "boids.py";
    for (index = 1; index < argc; index++)
    {
        args[index - 1] = argv[index];
    }
    args[argc] = NULL;
    return _execvp("python", args);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument in the `argv` vector is conventionally the fully qualified name of the executable to be started:

> The _spawnv, _spawnve, _spawnvp, and
>   _spawnvpe calls are useful when there is a variable number of arguments to
>   the new process. Pointers to the
>   arguments are passed as an array,
>   argv. The argument argv[0] is usually
>   a pointer to a path in real mode or to
>   the program name in protected mode,
>   and argv[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2%28VS.80%29.aspx) through argv[n] are
>   pointers to the character strings
>   forming the new argument list. The
>   argument argv[n +1] must be a NULL
>   pointer to mark the end of the
>   argument list.

(From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2%28VS.80%29.aspx))

Likewise:

> The _execv, _execve, _execvp, and
>   _execvpe calls are useful when the number of parameters to the new
>   process is variable. Pointers to the
>   parameters are passed as an array,
>   argv. The parameter argv[0] is usually
>   a pointer to cmdname. The parameters
>   argv[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2%28VS.80%29.aspx) through argv[n] point to the
>   character strings forming the new
>   parameter list. The parameter
>   argv[n+1] must be a NULL pointer to
>   mark the end of the parameter list.

([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/431x4c1w%28VS.80%29.aspx))